# Any real time scenario when we will need to call future method from batch class?

Tags: batch, future

I am trying to understand if there is any real time scenario when we will need to call future method from batch class ?

Can anyone please help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you expand more on why this question is coming up? There are many many many different answers to this question

Comment: This has been asked in one of my interview.

Comment: Batch and future are *both* asynchronous, not real-time.

Comment: I read that as "real life", David. But great point

Comment: @SebastianKessel The answer is "no": you can't call a future method in a batchable context.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no scenario where you would call a future method in a batchable method. This is because the system does not allow you to do so. If, for some reason, you need another asynchronous call, you must use Queueable. Note that you are limited to just one Queueable per execute method. This is called out in [Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm). Since you mentioned this is for an interview, it's worth studying this document carefully, since many interviewers will ask questions of this nature regarding governor limits.